# CLIPS deftemplate incorrect slot type

Tags: clips, expert-system

I am very puzzled by CLIPS. I have defined in a .clp file a deftemplate and a rule.

```
(deftemplate basic-ch "Basic characteristics template"
    (slot ch-name
        (type SYMBOL)
        (default ?DERIVE)
    )
    (slot score
        (type INTEGER)
        (default 1)
        (range 1 5)
    )
)
(defrule make-ch
    ?get-ch <- (get-ch TRUE)
    =>
    (printout t "Enter ch name" crlf)
    (bind ?name (read))
    (printout t "Enter ch score" crlf)
    (bind ?score (read))
    (assert (basic-ch (ch-name ?name) (score ?score)))
    (retract ?get-ch)
)
```

When i (assert (get-ch TRUE)) and (run), it prompts me for the ch name and score. However, if I enter a string for the score, the string score gets asserted by the rule! For example:

```
Enter ch name
hello
Enter ch score
hello
;(basic-ch (ch-name hello)(score hello)) get asserted?!
```

How is this possible? I have defined the score to be INTEGER and even provided the range. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Section 11, Constraint Attributes, of the Basic Programming Guide:

> Two types of constraint checking are supported: static and dynamic.
>   When static constraint checking is enabled, constraint violations are
>   checked when function calls and constructs are parsed. This includes
>   constraint checking between patterns on the LHS of a rule when
>   variables are used in more than one slot. When dynamic constraint
>   checking is enabled, newly created data objects (such as deftemplate
>   facts and instances) have their slot values checked for constraint
>   violations. Essentially, static constraint checking occurs when a
>   CLIPS program is loaded and dynamic constraint checking occurs when a
>   CLIPS program is running. By default, static constraint checking is
>   enabled and dynamic constraint checking is disabled. The default
>   behavior can be changed by using the set-static-constraint-checking
>   and set-dynamic-constraint-checking functions.

If you enable dynamic constraint checking, you'll get an error when you run your program:

```
CLIPS> (set-dynamic-constraint-checking TRUE)
TRUE
CLIPS> (assert (get-ch TRUE))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (run)
Enter ch name
hello
Enter ch score
hello

[CSTRNCHK1] Slot value hello found in fact f-2     
does not match the allowed types for slot score.
[PRCCODE4] Execution halted during the actions of defrule make-ch.
CLIPS>
```

Because it generates an error, dynamic constraint checking is useful for testing, but not for validating user input while a program is executing. If you want to validate use input, define some utility methods:

```
CLIPS> 
(defmethod get-integer ((?query STRING))
   (bind ?value FALSE)
   (while (not (integerp ?value))
      (printout t ?query " ")
      (bind ?value (read)))
   ?value)
CLIPS>  
(defmethod get-integer ((?query STRING) (?lower INTEGER) (?upper INTEGER))
   (bind ?value FALSE)
   (while (or (not (integerp ?value)) (< ?value ?lower) (> ?value ?upper))
      (printout t ?query " (" ?lower " - " ?upper ") ")
      (bind ?value (read)))
   ?value)
CLIPS> (get-integer "Pick an integer:")
Pick an integer: hello
Pick an integer: 3
3
CLIPS> (get-integer "Pick an integer" 1 5)
Pick an integer (1 - 5) -1
Pick an integer (1 - 5) hello
Pick an integer (1 - 5) 8
Pick an integer (1 - 5) 4
4
CLIPS>
```